# No content nodes after Umbraco 6 upgrade

Tags: umbraco

I asked this question in the Umbraco forum three days ago and haven't had a single answer. I have a website whose content I can no longer edit and I know the people at SO are the best, so here goes:

I just upgraded a site from Umbraco version 4.6.1 to 6.0.0 and now the only thing that displays in the content tab in the backend is a "Content" node. The whole tree has disappeared but the site actually still works it's just that I can't reach any of the content in the backend--Media, Settings, Developer, etc. tabs all appear to be working as normal.

If I right-click on the only visble node, "Content", I get "Create", "Sort", "Republish Entire Site" and "Reload nodes".

**Create** gives me the expected create dialog box but I don't want to try creating anything yet until I know what's wrong.

**Sort** throws the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.CMSNode..ctor(IUmbracoEntity entity) +32
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Content..ctor(IContentBase contentBase) +18
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document.<GetRootDocuments>b__1(IContent c) +38
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +325
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document.GetRootDocuments() +123
   umbraco.cms.presentation.sort.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +813
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

**Republish** works without error re-creating the umbraco.config file in the App_Data folder.

**Reload** nodes appears to be trying to, well, reload the nodes, but nothing shows up in the end.

I'm using a MySql database and I'm happy to hack at it with a few sql commands to get things working again as I suspect that a few errant node ids are probably to blame but I don't know what tables to look at.

All help gratefully received.

PS: Umbraco "About" shows the following version information -- "**Umbraco v6.0.0 (Assembly version: 1.0.4779.24222)**"

Comment: Please improve the formatting.

Comment: My apologies, Kimi, I did this on my Galaxy Note tablet and it was a big struggle to get the whole lot in. I'll improve it when I get to a computer.

Comment: Formatting improved...I hope this looks better and makes it easier to answer :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to ask the question - did you take a backup before the upgrade?

Comment: Yes I took a full backup of the site and the MySql database.

Comment: @oak, Awesome! Please refer to my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that rather than troubleshooting the issue at this point, which is more like chasing a rabbit down a hole, that you take a copy of your backups and attempt the upgrade again. It's possible that you could have missed a step in the upgrade process. Pay special attention to the [upgrade notes](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/Upgrading/general) and the [version specific upgrade notes](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/Upgrading/version-specific) (pretty much every version specific note can apply to you).

If you find that you still have problems after the second attempt, I'd suggest a more granular upgrade path, such as upgrading to highest version of 4.7, then to the highest 4.11, and then finally the highest of 6.0, again paying attention to the upgrade notes and checking after each upgrade that the site still works.

In either case make sure that you are running the installer at the end as this will allow umbraco to make some necessary changes to your database.